# How to structure Django models for multiple forms using a subset of a list of fields?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, django-forms

I am building a large, complex form system through Django. It is more complex than any form I have yet built, and I have some database design background but not a lot of experience with Django.

Let's say that there are about 500 possible questions, and 6 different form types. About 75% of the questions are common to all 6 forms, but the rest appear on 1-5 of the forms in various, somewhat overlapping combinations (for example, question 20 appears on forms A, B, and D, but question 21 appears on forms B, C, and D).

The possible solutions I've come up with so far are:

1) have one model that is all of the common questions and then a separate model for each form type (A, B, C, D, E, F) that inherits the common questions and then adds each thing that is not common. The downside to this is that there is redundancy between form types on some fields (those questions that appear on multiple forms).

2) have one table/model for all 500 questions, then have each form type linked to an intermediary table that lists which questions apply to which form type. This seems easy enough to do with raw SQL/on paper, but I can't figure out how to make it work in Django. If `FormAModel` has a ManyToMany field with `AllQuestionsModel`, it can't selectively grab only questions that apply to Form A this way, can it?

Edit: I'm realizing this is very similar to Django User permissions (users have roles, roles belong to different users), but Django has built out how to assign varying permissions to different users to make it quicker to set up. How might I go about duplicating this idea for a different set of models that become forms?

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried putting all your questions in one model:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(
        # parameters
        )
    form_a = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text='Question is on Form "A" ',
        )
    form_b = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text='Question is on Form "B" ',
        )
    form_c = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text='Question is on Form "C" ',
        )
    form_d = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text='Question is on Form "D" ',
        )
    form_e = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text='Question is on Form "E" ',
        )
    form_f = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text='Question is on Form "F" ',
        )
```

Then you can `query` the questions you want:

```
form_a = Questions.objects.filter(form_a=True)
```

Or if you want to get more indepth, you can try setting up custom  [`managers`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/).

Also, if it is easier to mark what `forms` the `Questions` are not on, set `default=True` instead of `default=False`. Good luck.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Where do you tell the question that it has the attribute form_a=True? Inside the definition of question_text, as a parameter? `question_text = models.CharField(form_a = true)`?

Comment: No. It is a separate field on the model. It will show up as checkbox when rendered. The question_text will be your question.

Comment: I forgot to mention when you display your question to the test taker, you only have to show `Question.question_text` so that they don’t see the checkboxes.